# Wearing Tefilin at the earliest Maariv possible

Tags: tefilin, maariv

Are there any halachic sources describing a case of someone who laid tefilin before before plag and daven Mincha with, does he have to remove them after plag (when it is still day time) before starting Maariv? or can he keep wearing them during Maariv?

Comment: Mishna Berura 30 sk 8 and beir heitiv there 3

Comment: https://nosachteiman.co.il/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A5-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F-4/

Answer (score 5):

[This responsum](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=he&pageid=48&cat=1&newsletter=1282&article=4815) from the Rabbis of Eretz Hemdah permit an individual who was already wearing *tefillin* to keep them on while praying *arvit* while it is still daytime.

Comment: An additional consideration: If the rest of the shul is **not** wearing *t'fillin* during *ma'ariv*, there may be reason for an individual to comport with this behavior since wearing *t'fillin* might be perplexing and confusing to other congregants ("דבר תמוה", see Igros Moshe [OC V 38:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=165), T'fillas David §13, and Bach OC 293 s.v. "וכתב הרי"צ גיאת" based on Hagahos Maharshal on the Tur for other examples of this principle). If the individual had not yet worn *t'fillin* that day, he should perhaps do so off to the side or in private.